# How did Lucy end up with Cecil?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-room-with-a-view

In *Room With A View* Lucy (Helena Bonham Carter) begins a doomed engagement to Cecil, an uptight and diffident man. How did Lucy end up engaged to Cecil in the first place? What did she see in him?

Comment: Cecil was "A sophisticated London aesthete whose rank and class make him a desirable match". She saw the means to a good life through one of the few avenues available to women at the time -- making a good catch. This is a fairly common plot device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cecil persisted

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Room_with_a_View) reminds us in this article on E M Forster's book:

> In Rome, Lucy spends time with Cecil Vyse, whom she knew in England. Cecil twice proposes to Lucy in Italy; she rejects him both times. As Part Two begins, Lucy has returned to Surrey, England, to her family home, Windy Corner. Cecil proposes yet again and this time she accepts. Cecil is a sophisticated London aesthete whose rank and class make him a desirable match, despite his despising country society; he is a rather comic figure who is snobbish and gives himself pretentious airs.

In English society a young eligible woman could only resist proposals for so long, unless there was a strong inbuilt resistance to marriage and social pressures in general. Lucy would have been under family and societal pressure to marry, and Cecil emerged as one of the more superficially agreeable and persistent suitors.

The movie does not give any attention to the backstory of Lucy and Cecil's relationship - even less than the novel - making his introduction seem rather sudden and unexplained.